# Mistake while evaluating the gaussian integral with imaginary term in exponent

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am trying to evaluate the integral $I=\int_0^\infty e^{-ix^2}\,dx$ as one component of evaluating a contour integral but I am dropping a factor of $1/2$ and after checking my work many times, I worry that I am making a conceptual mistake in moving to polar coordinates for the interval $(0,\infty)$ rather than $(-\infty,\infty)$. Below is my work:

$$
\begin{align*}
  \text{Define } I&=\int_0^R e^{-ix^2} \, dx=\int_0^R e^{-iy^2} \, dy \\
  \text{then } I^2&=\int_0^R e^{-ix^2} \, dx \int_0^R e^{-iy^2} \, dy \\
  &\Rightarrow I^2=\int_0^R\int_0^R e^{-ix^2}e^{-iy^{2}} \, dx \, dy \\
  &\Rightarrow I^2=\int_0^R\int_0^R e^{-i(x^2+y^2)} \, dx \, dy
\end{align*}
$$

And converting to polar coordinates, with jacobian $r$ for the integral,
and taking $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ since we are integrating in the first quadrant,
we have:

\begin{align*}
  I^2&=\int_0^\pi\int_0^R e^{-i(r^2\cos^2(\theta)+r^2 \sin^2(\theta))} r \, dr \, d\theta\\
  I^2&=\int_0^\pi\int_0^R e^{-i(r^2)} r \, dr \, d\theta\\
\end{align*}
Which we can now perform a u substitution on:
$u=r^2\Rightarrow \frac{du}{2r}=dr$, yielding
\begin{align*}
  I^2&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi\int_{0=r}^{R=r}e^{-iu} \, du \, d\theta\\
  &\Rightarrow I^2=\frac{\pi}{2} \left[\frac{-e^{-iR^2}}{i}+\frac{1}{i}\right] \\
  &\Rightarrow I^2=\frac{\pi}{2i}[1-e^{-iR^2}] \\
  &\Rightarrow I=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2i}}\sqrt{1-e^{-iR^2}}
\end{align*}
Then in the limit $R\rightarrow \infty$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2i}}\sqrt{1-e^{-iR^{2}}}=
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2i}}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in my eyes that you allow the polar angle to be in $\phi\in[0,\pi]$ although just integrating over a quadrant integration domain in cartesian coordinates,$(x,y)\in[0,R]^2$. I'd suggest putting $\phi\in[0,\pi/2]$ in order to account for the integration in the first quadrant. This modification of your calculation results in an additional factor of $1/2$ when going to polars $(r,\phi)$.

$I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4i}}\sqrt{1-e^{-iR^2}}$.

The limit $R\to\infty$ works for practical purposes.

Does this help you?

David

Comment: I thought that might be it, and revisiting it in context (i want to restrict myself to the positive reals in the complex plane) this makes sense. Thank you! I was pulling my hair out

Comment: This answer misses something.  See my posted answer. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

The integral $\displaystyle\int_0^R\int_0^R\cdots \,dx\,dy$ is over a **square**, $[0,R]^2$.

But the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^\text{something} \int_0^R \cdots \, r \, dr \, d\theta$ is over a **sector of a circle**, with an arc of a circle as a part of its boundary.

Comment: so is it not possible to convert to polar coordinates and still be integrating over the rectangle?

Comment: ah I see on the wikipedia page now, thank you for alerting me to this!

Comment: @qbert : You can integrate over the rectangle in polar coordinates, but in that case the bounds of integration are more complicated. $\qquad$

Comment: Got it. Should I really have this $\sqrt{i}$ term in the denominator?

Comment: I don't see that you need $\sqrt i$ in the denominator. $\qquad$

Comment: but the antiderivative of, after u substitution in polar coordinates, $e^{-iu}$ should be $-\frac{e^{-iu}}{i}$ no?

Comment: @qbert : Yes, but why would that involve $\sqrt i$? $\qquad$

Comment: But then I take square root of $I^2$ to get I

Comment: ok, You meant after evaluating the integral.  Yes that appears to be true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39156/discussion-between-qbert-and-michael-hardy).